# gRPC and multitenancy in a Zero Trust envirionment

Tags: security, grpc, multi-tenant

I need to implement gRPC services in a multitenancy environment. But I have doubts if gRPC supports multitenancy?

I'm also working in a zero trust architecture.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your idea is, since Kafka doesn't interact with gRPC, but sure, a gRPC server can accept requests from many clients. A Kafka topic can also accept multiple producers and be read by multiple consumers

Comment: Thank you for your response! And I'm sorry because I think I expressed myself badly. The main question is whether gRPC can implement multitenancy. Would it be possible?

Thank  youu in advance!

Comment: Like I said, a gRPC server can support multiple clients, sure. What issues are you having with it?

Comment: Thank you so much OneCricketeer!
This is a research work we are doing before using gRPC in the project. And we need to know if gRPC supports multitenancy (thank you for your response :) ) and also how it behaves when there are different perimeter protection devices in a network ... seems that this may be a problem :(

Comment: A firewall is irrelevant to the protocol that is used.

Comment: So ... if I want to access a server (with gRPC) that is behind a firewall, I won't have any problems?

Comment: If the server ports are opened, then you shouldn't. However, your server might have further authorization requirements. This isn't unique to gRPC. The same answer applies to any server on the network.